# How to identify columns with non english values in postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My table has both English and non English characters and i want to extract the rows with non English characters using postgresql 9.4

For example: My table has the following rows

```
column 1        column 2
1               rivoluzionando così ilmodo di fare musica
2               Recortes diseñados específicamente
3               All included
4               price is inclusive
5               welcome kit
6               La continua evoluzione del mondo
```

and i want the output as below

```
column 1        column 2
1               rivoluzionando così ilmodo di fare musica
2               Recortes diseñados específicamente
6               La continua evoluzione del mondo
```

Comment: Try `char_length(colname) <> octet_length(colname)` It should work at least for the UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Do you mean non-English *characters* or non-English *words* ?

Comment: I meant non english words like FR, DE, JP, ESP and so on

Comment: i tried this char_length(colname) <> octet_length(colname) and got the following error             ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Answer (score 0):

Download a Dictionary, create a table with it's data and check if there is a word in your column, which isn't in the dictionary.

maybe if you download the xml file from here: [http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php](http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php/)